# Populate and download docx file with user input

Tags: python, django, docx

I am not able to pass the user's name from the database to the docx file in views.py

I am trying to implement the following:

1- User enters name, submits, gets redirected to

2- Page with download button. When clicked,

3- docx file gets generated with user's name as filename.

Here's what I have

**models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**views.py**

```
class BookingView(ListView):
    model = Booking
    template_name = "docbuilder/doc_maker.html"
    doc = Document()
    doc.add_paragraph('this_is_where_name_should_go')
    doc.save('this_is_also_where_name_should_go.docx')
    template = 'docbuilder/doc_maker.html'
```

**doc_maker.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

     <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <select>
            {% for i in object_list %}
          <option value="{{ i.name }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Download">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Asking for mercy doesn't tend to get you any. I suggest you read a bit on how to write a good question. The main problem with this question is that it's too broad; you're basically asking us to do 75% of your work for you. Strip this down to whatever's blocking your progress *right now*, and nothing more. Give us whatever code is refusing to budge, and all unexpected behaviours, crashes and tracebacks that are relevant. We'll help you get over the molehills, but the mountain is your just to climb.

Comment: @Veedrac I updated to the best of my comprehension. PS The problem isn't bugs or errors. The problem is that I do not know where to begin. You're wrong if you think it makes sense for someone to uselessly flip and scroll through pages of texts for hours on end just so s/he can do some form of due diligence. Sometimes it's not about a hike or some hill, but about having a compass.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't designed for compasses. I suggest you ask somewhere else if that's what you want. But you have a semivalid question now ("How do pass the user's name between these files."), although you're probably not going to get much attention because of the way your question is written. Strip this post down to *only* the immediate question and say what you've tried and you'll get a much better response from the community.

Comment: @veedrac Where do you suggest I ask? Oh wait... Right. Not a valid question. Thanks for nothing. Just trying to learn here.

Comment: If you just said "Where do you suggest I ask?" I would have recommended a few places, such as the Python mailing list and Stack Overflow chat. Since you are rude about it, I doubt they would want to help much either, though. If you're not willing to be kind to the people you're asking to do all your work, I suggest you try and solve your question with a good programming book instead.

Comment: @veedrac If you thought I was being rude, I apologize... I tend to always be kind to those who help. Anyways, thanks for all the help. It's touching how helpful and relevant you've been to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to populate the docx fields.

I'll update it soon enough for the download feature.

My solution

**models**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**views 1**

Presents a text field and stores the name

```
class BookingCreate(CreateView):
    model = Booking
    success_url = 'docbuilder/download.html'
```

**forms**

Creates drop down menu with all stored names

```
class DocForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Booking.objects.all().order_by('name'))
```

**views 2**

Displays drop down menu with stored names and creates docx with selected data and stores it locally

```
def BookingView(request):
    form = DocForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            doc = Document()
            doc.add_paragraph('It worked!')
            doc.save(('{0}.docx').format(name))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('congrats.html')
    return render(request, 'docbuilder/doc_maker.html',{'form': form })
```

**templates**

```
 <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="Download">
 </form>
```